# cinnamon keep window below

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I'm running Mint 17 with cinnamon, I know you can "Always Top" a window, but I can't find a way to "Always Bottom" a window.

In fact, I'm running a fullscreen app (remote-viewer), but I wish all other applications never go behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finally using [devilspie](http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie) and [gdevilspie](https://code.google.com/p/gdevilspie/) with a config like this:

```
( if 
( begin 
( contains ( window_name ) "something_in_windows_name" )
) 
( begin 
( fullscreen )
( below )
( println "match" )
)
)
```

it will set the windows with "something_in_windows_name" to fullscreen + force below any other (except the background with icons etc)